# Is there any difference between System cache clear and drush cc all in Drupal 7.53

Tags: javascript, caching, drupal-7, missing-data, drush

I am facing a unique issue with the clear cache. The issue is coming in Drupal 7.53 project. When someone clear the cache from performance page then it removes some java script files from the DOM and UI is disturbed in absence of Javascript in the project.

To resolve this we have to open the module page and save it again. After that have to clean cache using drush (drush cc all) and then it starts workings with all JS loaded in the DOM.

I tried to fix this issue by adding the missing Javascript files in the hook_init forcefully but It was surprising for me. I found that now there is no need to save the modules page. Now it works by clearing the cache using drush (drush cc all). Means if cache is cleared from the perfomance page (admin/config/development/performance) then it is necessary to clear the cache using drush otherwise JS will not work well.

If cache is cleared from performance page or flush all cache then there are following errors comes in the console. [console-errors-after-system-clear-cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz3ft.png)

If I add the js forcefully in hook_init then there are some other errors in console.
[Image -console-error-after-applying-js-in-hook-init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxOnQ.png)

I don't understand what is the difference between system clear cache and drush cc all. Using drush everything works.

I tried to find the difference between drush cc all and system clear cache but didn't do it exactly. Has someone faced this issue? What should I do to fix the same?